# How can I view my FPS in Diablo 3?

Tags: diablo-iii

So, my gameplay is a little bit pokey at the highest resolution/detail levels, and I'd like to tweak things to get better performance, but it's difficult without being able to objectively measure my framerate. How can I display it?

(This is on a Mac, so using [FRAPS](http://www.fraps.com/) is out.)

Answer (score 42, accepted):

On Windows, you can press <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> to toggle framerate display. On mac you can use <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>

Comment: Ctrl+R does the trick!

Comment: Note that with the current build there is a known bug and the game displays the framerate as 0 fps: http://us.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/5884818685

Answer (score 8):

command R also works for mac for showing FPS